# $L \otimes_K L$ is isomorphic to $\prod_{\sigma \in G} L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $ K \subset L$ be a finite Galois extension. Let $G$ be the Galois group.

Let $L^G = \prod_{\sigma \in G} L$ denote copies of $L$ indexed by the group $G$. I want to show that the map
\begin{align*}
L \otimes_K L &\to L^G\\
a \otimes b &\mapsto (a\sigma(b))_{\sigma \in G}
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism.

How can I show that?